# Incorporating instance 'count' into list joined into string (Python3)

Tags: python, concatenation

First time asking a question on SO, so please bear with me.

In the python program I'm writing, I am trying to avoid concatenation of a string in a for loop by using the join method (because: efficiency), but I would like for the program to put a count next to each instance.

For example:

> [1] First item [2] Second item [3] Third item

From what I understand (I'm not a master pythoner), this form of using .join() is utilizing a list comprehension, and I can't seem to figure out the proper syntax to do what I'm trying to.

```
temporary_list = ["First item", "Second item", "Third item"]
count = 1
display = "\n".join("> [{}] {}".format((count), t), count += 1 for t in temporary_list[:10])
```

I could easily do this with a for loop:

```
    for t in temporary_list[:10]:
            display += "> [{}] {}\n".format(count, t)
            count += 1
```

I have a similar line of code that works fine without counting.

```
display = "\n".join("> {}: {}".format(t, display_correctly(number_list[t])) for t in temporary_list[:10])
```

I've tried playing with the parenthesis, using 'and' and a lot of googling. Is there a way to do this?

If it matters, I'm using python 3.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, you need `enumerate`:

```
temporary_list = ["First item", "Second item", "Third item"]
print("\n".join("> [{}] {}".format(n, i) for n, i in enumerate(temporary_list, start=1)))
```

Output:

```
> [1] First item
> [2] Second item
> [3] Third item
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Enumerate was the missing link. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
"\n".join("> [{}] {}".format((count), t) for count, t in zip(range(len(temporary_list[:10])), temporary_list[:10]))
```

My bad, this works now

Comment: That was fast. It was missing a couple of parenthesis, but I ran it and got: TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Sorry I fixed the code, but enumerate looks way better I admit.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print out the index of items in the list. But if you want to count the number of occurences of each item in a list use [Counter()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
temporary_list = ["First item", "Second item", "Third item"]

for index,value in enumerate(temporary_list):
    print(f'[{index+1}]', value)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[1] First item
[2] Second item
[3] Third item
```

If you want to print out horizontally:

```
temporary_list = ["First item", "Second item", "Third item"]
print(" ".join([f'[{index+1}] {value}' for index,value in enumerate(temporary_list)]))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[1] First item [2] Second item [3] Third item
```

Comment: The counting was strictly for displaying purposes and not stored. Your code answers the question, though, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, your title say occurrence count. I was thinking you want to count the occurrences of each items in the list.

Comment: I apologize for my limitations in figuring out a clearer wording. The method this code is built into has a user-defined list. If that list has more than 10 items, it's broken into different pages. I thought it would look nicer to have an index alongside each entry (and if it goes to the second page, the first item would be 1 again instead of 11). That's what I meant by counting.